# Бесконечный цикл в Alien Invasion

Tags: python

Всем доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с проблемой на завершающем этапе первого проекта "Alien Invasion" в книге Эрика Метиза - "Изучаем Python". Последней задачей в проекте было написание кода, который выводит на экран обозначение трех жизней корабля. Они должны уменьшатся по мере столкновения корабля с пришельцами или достижением их края экрана. Затем игра должна прерваться, а статистика обнулиться. Однако у меня после первого столкновения исчезает одна жизнь и затем начинается бесконечный цикл игры, жизни не исчезают, а игра не останавливается. Очень прошу помощи, так как сутки пытаюсь найти этот недуг и до сих пор не получилось( Понимаю, что скорее всего хожу вокруг да около проблемы, но ошибку в упор не вижу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересно, что перед добавлением изображения жизней на экран - все работало исправно.

Я новичок в работе с Python, прошу не судить строго. Заранее спасибо!

Прикрепляю модули игры, в которых, как мне кажется, таится ошибка:

alien_invasion.py:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from game_stats import GameStats
from button import Button
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien
from scoreboard import Scoreboard

class AlienInvasion():
    """Класс для управления ресурсами и поведением игры."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Инициализирует игру и создает игровые ресурсы."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        """это экран игры"""
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Инопланетное вторжение, братик")

        # Создание экземпляров для хранения статистики
        # и панели результатов.
        self.stats = GameStats(self)
        self.sb = Scoreboard(self)

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self._create_fleet()

        # Игра Alien Invasion запускается в неактивном состоянии.
        self.game_active = False

        # Создание кнопку Play.
        self.play_button = Button(self, "Play")

        #  Создает доп. кнопочки
        self._make_difficulty_buttons()

    def _make_difficulty_buttons(self):
        """Создает кнопки, позволяющие выбрать уровень сложности."""
        self.easy_button = Button(self, "Easy")
        self.medium_button = Button(self, "Medium")
        self.hard_button = Button(self, "Hard")

        # Распологает кнопки так, чтобы они не наседали одна на другую.
        self.easy_button.rect.top = (
            self.play_button.rect.top + 1.5*self.play_button.rect.height)
        self.easy_button._update_msg_position()

        self.medium_button.rect.top = (
            self.easy_button.rect.top + 1.5*self.easy_button.rect.height)
        self.medium_button._update_msg_position
        
        self.hard_button.rect.top = (
            self.medium_button.rect.top + 1.5*self.hard_button.rect.height)
        self.hard_button._update_msg_position()

        # Инициализируйте среднюю кнопку выделенным цветом.
        self.medium_button.set_highlighted_color()

    def run_game(self):
        """Запуск основного цикла игры."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()

            if self.game_active:
                self.ship.update()
                self._update_bullets()
                self._update_aliens()
                
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Обрабатывает нажатия клавиш и события мыши."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                self._check_play_button(mouse_pos)
                self._check_difficulty_buttons(mouse_pos)

    def _check_play_button(self, mouse_pos):
        """Запускает новую игру при нажатии кнопки Play."""
        button_clicked = self.play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        if button_clicked and not self.game_active:
            self._start_game()

    def _check_difficulty_buttons(self, mouse_pos):
        """Предлагает выбрать уровень сложности."""
        easy_button_clicked = self.easy_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        medium_button_clicked = self.medium_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        hard_button_clicked = self.hard_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
        if easy_button_clicked:
            self.settings.hard_level = 'easy'
            self.easy_button.set_highlighted_color()
            self.medium_button.set_base_color()
            self.hard_button.set_base_color()
            self._start_game()
        elif medium_button_clicked:
            self.settings.hard_level = 'medium'
            self.easy_button.set_base_color()
            self.medium_button.set_highlighted_color()
            self.hard_button.set_base_color()
            self._start_game()
        elif hard_button_clicked:
            self.settings.hard_level = 'hard'
            self.easy_button.set_base_color()
            self.medium_button.set_base_color()
            self.hard_button.set_highlighted_color()
            self._start_game()

    def _start_game(self):
        """Старт новой игры."""
        # Сброс игровых настроек.
        self.settings.initialize_dynamic_settings()
            
        # Сброс игровой статистики.
        self.stats.reset_stats()
        self.sb.prep_score()
        self.sb.prep_level()
        self.sb.prep_ships()
        self.game_active = True

        # Очистка списков пришельцев и снарядов.
        self.aliens.empty()
        self.bullets.empty()

        # Создание нового флота и размещение корабля в центре.
        self._create_fleet()
        self.ship.center_ship()
        # Указатель мыши скрывается.
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Реагирует на нажатие клавиш."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Реагирует на отпускание клавиш."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """Создание нового снаряда и включение его в группу bullets."""
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_bullets(self):
        """Обновляет позиции снарядов и уничтожает старые снаряды."""
        # Обновление позиций снарядов.
        self.bullets.update()

        # Удаление снарядов, вышедших за край экрана.
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

        self._check_bullet_alien_collisions()

    def _check_bullet_alien_collisions(self):
        """Обработка коллизий снарядов с пришельцами."""
        # Удаление снарядов и пришельцев, участвующих в коллизиях.
        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
            self.bullets, self.aliens, True, True)
        
        if collisions:
            # Любой снаряд, столкнувшийся с пришельцем, становится 
            # ключом словаря collisions. С каждым снарядом связывается
            # значение — список пришельцев, участвующих в коллизии. 
            # Переберем словарь collisions и убедимся в том, 
            # что очки начисляются за каждого подбитого пришельца
            for aliens in collisions.values():
                self.stats.score += self.settings.alien_points * len(aliens)
            self.sb.prep_score()
            self.sb.check_high_score()

        if not self.aliens:
            # Уничтожение существующих снарядов и создание нового флота.
            self.bullets.empty()
            self._create_fleet()
            self.settings.increase_speed()

            # Увеличение уровня.
            self.stats.level += 1
            self.sb.prep_level()

    def _update_aliens(self):
        """
        Проверяет, достиг ли флот края экрана,
        с последующим обновлением позиций всех пришельцев во флоте.
        """
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()

        # Проверка коллизий "пришелец — корабль".
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.ship, self.aliens):
            self._ship_hit()

        # Проверяет, добрались ли пришельцы до нижнего края экрана.
        self._check_aliens_bottom()

    def _ship_hit(self):
        """Обрабатывает столкновение корабля с пришельцем."""
        if self.stats.ships_left > 0:
            # Уменьшение ships_left и обновление панели счета
            self.stats.ships_left -= 1
            self.sb.prep_ships()
            
            # Очистка списков пришельцев и снарядов.
            self.aliens.empty()
            self.bullets.empty()

            # Сброс игровой статистики
            self.stats.reset_stats()
            self.game_active = True
            self.sb.prep_score()
            
            # Создание нового флота и размещение корабля в центре.
            self._create_fleet()
            self.ship.center_ship()
            
            # Пауза.
            sleep(0.5)
        else:
            self.game_active = False
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
            
    def _create_fleet(self):
        """Создает флот пришельцев."""
        # Создание пришельца и вычисление количества пришельцев в ряду
        # Интервал между соседними пришельцами равен ширине пришельца.
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
        number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)

        """Определяет количество рядов, помещающихся на экране."""
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height -
                                (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)

        # Создание флота вторжения.
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)

    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        """Создание пришельца и размещение его в ряду."""
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien_width = alien.rect.width
        alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        """Реагирует на достижение пришельцем края экрана."""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        """Опускает весь флот и меняет направление флота."""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1 

    def _check_aliens_bottom(self):
        """Проверяет, добрались ли пришельцы до нижнего края экрана."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
                # Происходит то же, что при столкновении с кораблем.
                self._ship_hit()
                break

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Обновляет изображения на экране и отображает новый экран."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)

        # Вывод информации о счете.
        self.sb.show_score()

        # Кнопка Play отображается в том случае, если игра неактивна.
        if not self.game_active:
            self.play_button.draw_button()
            self.easy_button.draw_button()
            self.medium_button.draw_button()
            self.hard_button.draw_button()
            
        # Отображение последнего прорисованного экрана.
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Создание экземпляра и запуск игры.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

settings.py:

```
class Settings():
    """Класс для хранения всех настроек игры Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Инициализирует статические настройки игры."""
        # Настройки экрана
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230,230,230)

        # Настройки корабля
        self.ship_limit = 3

        # Параметры снаряда
        self.bullet_width = 300
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullets_allowed = 3

        # Настройки пришельцев
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10

        # Темп ускорения игры
        self.speedup_scale = 1.1
        # Темп роста стоимости пришельцев
        self.score_scale = 1.5

        self.hard_level = 'medium'

        self.initialize_dynamic_settings()

    def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):
        """Инициализирует настройки, изменяющиеся в ходе игры."""
        if self.hard_level == 'easy':
            self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
            self.bullet_speed_factor = 2.5
            self.alien_speed_factor = 0.5
        elif self.hard_level == 'medium':
            self.ship_speed_factor = 2.5
            self.bullet_speed_factor = 3.5
            self.alien_speed_factor = 1.5
        elif self.hard_level == 'hard':
            self.ship_speed_factor = 3.0
            self.bullet_speed_factor = 4.0
            self.alien_speed_factor = 2.5

        # fleet_direction = 1 обозначает движение вправо; а -1 - влево.
        self.fleet_direction = 1

        # Подсчет очков
        self.alien_points = 50

    def increase_speed(self):
        """Увеличивает настройки скорости и стоимость пришельцев."""
        self.ship_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
        self.bullet_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
        self.alien_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
        self.alien_points = int(self.alien_points * self.score_scale)
```

game_stats.py:

```
class GameStats():
    """Отслеживание статистики для игры Alien Invasion."""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Инициализирует статистику."""
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.reset_stats()
        
        # Рекорд не должен сбрасываться.
        self.high_score = 0

    def reset_stats(self):
        """Инициализирует статистику, изменяющуюся в ходе игры."""
        self.ships_left = self.settings.ship_limit
        self.score = 0
        self.level = 1
```

scoreboard.py:

```
import pygame.font
from pygame.sprite import Group

from ship import Ship

class Scoreboard():
    """Класс для вывода игровой информации."""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Инициализирует атрибуты подсчета очков."""
        self.ai_game = ai_game
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.stats = ai_game.stats

        # Настройки шрифта для вывода счета.
        self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
        # Подготовка изображений счетов.
        self.prep_score()
        self.prep_high_score()
        self.prep_level()
        self.prep_ships()

    def prep_score(self):
        """Преобразует текущий счет в графическое изображение."""
        rounded_score = round(self.stats.score, -1)
        score_str = "{:,}".format(rounded_score)
        text_1 =  'Score: {0}'.format(score_str)
        self.score_image = self.font.render(text_1, True,
                self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)
        
        # Вывод счета в правой верхней части экрана.
        self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
        self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.score_rect.top = 20

    def prep_high_score(self):
        """Преобразует рекордный счет в графическое изображение."""
        high_score = round(self.stats.high_score, -1)
        high_score_str = "{:,}".format(high_score)
        text_2 = 'High Score: {0}'.format(high_score_str)
        self.high_score_image = self.font.render(text_2, True,
                self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)
        
        # Рекорд выравнивается по центру верхней стороны.
        self.high_score_rect = self.high_score_image.get_rect()
        self.high_score_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.high_score_rect.top = self.score_rect.top

    def check_high_score(self):
       """Проверяет, появился ли новый рекорд."""
       if self.stats.score > self.stats.high_score:
           self.stats.high_score = self.stats.score
           self.prep_high_score() 

    def prep_level(self):
        """Преобразует уровень в графическое изображение."""
        level_str = str(self.stats.level)
        text_3 = 'Level: %s' % level_str
        self.level_image = self.font.render(text_3, True,
            self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)
        
        # Уровень выводится под текущим счетом.
        self.level_rect = self.level_image.get_rect()
        self.level_rect.right = self.score_rect.right
        self.level_rect.top = self.score_rect.bottom + 10

    def prep_ships(self):
        """Сообщает количество оставшихся кораблей."""
        self.ships = Group()
        for ship_number in range(self.stats.ships_left):
            ship = Ship(self.ai_game)
            ship.rect.x = 10 + ship_number * ship.rect.width
            ship.rect.y = 10
            self.ships.add(ship)

    def show_score(self):
        """Выводит текущий счет, рекорд, уровень и число оставшихся кораблей."""
        self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.high_score_image, self.high_score_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.level_image, self.level_rect)
        self.ships.draw(self.screen)
```

ship.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Ship(Sprite):
    """Класс для управления кораблем."""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Инициализирует корабль и задает его начальную позицию."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # Загружает изображение корабля и получает прямоугольник.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Каждый новый корабль появляется у нижнего края экрана.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

        # Сохранение вещественной координаты центра корабля.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

        # Флаг перемещения
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """Обновляет позицию корабля с учетом флага."""
        # Обновляется атрибут x, не rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed_factor

        # Обновление атрибута rect на основании self.x.
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def blitme(self):
        """Рисует корабль в текущей позиции."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def center_ship(self):
        """Размещает корабль в центре нижней стороны."""
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
```

Comment: какая переменная отвечает за жизни?

Comment: @DaniilLoban shipsleft

Comment: что-то я не вижу ее в этих файлах

Comment: @DaniilLoban ищите плохо. self.ships_left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательно посмотрим на этот метод:

```py
def _ship_hit(self):
    # ЕСЛИ У КОРАБЛЯ ОСТАЛИСЬ ЖИЗНИ 
    # (их количество больше 0)
    if self.stats.ships_left > 0: 
        self.stats.ships_left -= 1
        self.sb.prep_ships()
        
        # Очистка списков пришельцев и снарядов. (???)
        ...

        # Сброс игровой статистики (???)
        ...
        
        # Создание нового флота и размещение корабля в центре.
        ...

        # Пауза
        ...
    
    # ИНАЧЕ ЕСЛИ У КОРАБЛЯ НЕ ОСТАЛОСЬ ЖИЗНЕЙ
    else:
        self.game_active = False
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

Из комментариев мы можем сделать вывод, что даже если корабль ещё имеет жизни код полностью сбрасывается, а если жизни кончились, то мы останавливаем игру. Исходя из следующего фрагмента кода в методе `run`:

```py
while True:
    self._check_events()
    # Пока игра активна
    if self.game_active:
        self.ship.update()
        self._update_bullets()
        self._update_aliens()
    # Если игра не активна,
    # то просто обновляем экран
    # без каких либо действий
    self._update_screen()
```

можно сделать вывод, что при self.game_active = False игра просто замирает и перестаёт обновлять инпуты, корабли и всё в таком роде.

Первым делом давайте разделим логику перезапуска игры. В `alien_invasion.py` добавляем

```py
def reset_game(self):
    # Очистка списков пришельцев и снарядов.
    self.aliens.empty()
    self.bullets.empty()

    # Сброс игровой статистики
    self.stats.reset_stats()
    self.game_active = True
    self.sb.prep_score()
    
    # Создание нового флота и размещение корабля в центре.
    self._create_fleet()
    self.ship.center_ship()
```

А затем изменяем метод `_ship_hit` на более простой и понятный

```py
def _ship_hit(self):
    # ЕСЛИ У КОРАБЛЯ ОСТАЛИСЬ ЖИЗНИ 
    # (их количество больше 0)
    if self.stats.ships_left > 0:
        self.stats.ships_left -= 1
        self.sb.prep_ships()
    # ЕСЛИ ЖИЗНИ КОНЧИЛИСЬ
    else:
        self.reset_game()
```

Comment: Да, у кода в вопросе явно проблема с тем, что контроль над состоянием игры размазан по разным частям кода, к добру такое никогда не приводит.

Comment: Переделал, как Вы сказали, но поведение игры не изменилось(

Comment: Нашел ошибку - # Сброс игровой статистики self.stats.reset_stats() self.game_active = True self.sb.prep_score(). Эта часть заставляла цикл работать без остановки.

Comment: Большое спасибо, что заставили сконцентрироваться на проблемном методе, Ваши замечания также внес в свой код. И также спасибо тем, кто пытался в код вникнуть:D